# Regex Gedit replace comma to dot between number

Tags: regex, gedit

I have this kind of data in my file:

```
'208137, 6 ' '94057, 47 ' '698572, 87 '
```

And I want to replace just the comma with a dot:

```
'208137.6' '94057.47' '698572.87'
```

Why? Because the file has more commas for other purposes. Example:

```
investimentoEstimado2017 =  '735030, 15 ', investimentoEstimado2018 =  '735030, 15 ', investimentoEstimado2019 =  '306262, 5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the replacement for your given example you could capture 2 groups and replace with `\1.\2` (group1 dot group2):

[`('\d+), (\d+) ?(?=')`](https://regex101.com/r/R7r2pV/2)

That would match:

- `('\d+)` A single quote and one or more digits in a capturing group **(group 1)**
- `,` Then match a comma and a whitespace
- `(\d+)` And capture one or more digits in a second capturing group **(group 2)**
- `(?=')` Then match an optional whitespace and use a positive lookahead that asserts what follows is a single quote

Comment: Thanks "The fourth bird"